# Insertar datos en una tabla a partir de una búsqueda de otras tabla

Tags: c#, formularios, sql-server-2019

Buen día, hago una búsqueda con esta consulta:

```
select a.Cliente,b.Nombre,a.Referencia,e.Articulo,c.Descripcion1,d.CantidadRecibida,d.EstadoArt,d.AptoVenta,d.AlmacenDestino,d.Observaciones,d.Imagen from Venta a left join Cte b on a.Cliente = b.Cliente left join VentaD e on a.id = e.id left join Art c on c.Articulo = e.Articulo left join Devoluciones2023 d on d.Referencia = a.MovID where a.Referencia like '%" + tbBuscaFolio.Text + "%'
```

donde me llena los textbox de cliente, nombre, referencia, artículo, descripción y los restantes los inserto de manera manual para que se guarden en la tabla Devoluciones2023, pero cuando le doy clic al botón registrar no hace nada y no me marca algún error de porque no se insertan. Agradecería de su asesoría.

```
private void btnRegistrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.conexion);
            con.Open();
            string cadena = "INSERT INTO Devoluciones2023 (Nombre, Cliente, Referencia, Articulo, Descripcion1, CantidadRecibida, EstadoArt, AptoVenta, AlmacenDestino, Observaciones ) " +
                    "values ('@Nombre','@Cliente','@Referencia','@Articulo','@Descripcion1',@CantidadRecibida,'@EstadoArt','@AptoVenta','@AlmacenDestino','@Observaciones')";
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(cadena, con);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@Nombre", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            comando.Parameters["@Nombre"].Value = txtNombre.Text;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@Cliente", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            comando.Parameters["@Cliente"].Value = txtClave.Text;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@Referencia", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            comando.Parameters["@Referencia"].Value = txtFolio.Text;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@Articulo", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            comando.Parameters["@Articulo"].Value = txtArticulo.Text;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@Descripcion1", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            comando.Parameters["@Descripcion1"].Value = txtDescripcion.Text;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@CantidadRecibida", SqlDbType.Int);
            comando.Parameters["@CantidadRecibida"].Value = int.Parse(txtCantidad.Text);
            comando.Parameters.Add("@EstadoArt", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            comando.Parameters["@EstadoArt"].Value = txtEstado.Text;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@AptoVenta", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            comando.Parameters["@AptoVenta"].Value = cboVenta.Text;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@AlmacenDestino", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            comando.Parameters["@AlmacenDestino"].Value = cboAlmacen.Text;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@Observaciones", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            comando.Parameters["@Observaciones"].Value = txtObservaciones.Text;

            int cant;
            cant = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (cant == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Se modificaron los datos de la devolución");
                txtNombre.Text = "";
txtClave.Text = "";
                txtFolio.Text = "";
                txtArticulo.Text = "";
                txtDescripcion.Text = "";
                txtCantidad.Text = "";
                txtEstado.Text = "";
                cboVenta.Text = "";
                cboAlmacen.Text = "";
                txtObservaciones.Text = "";
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("No existe una devolución con el código ingresado");
            con.Close();
            btnRegistrar.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Si la memoria no me falla creo que no necesitas ' ' en el string de conexión.
```
"values (@Nombre,@Cliente,@Referencia,@Articulo,@Descripcion1,@CantidadRecibida,@EstadoArt,@AptoVenta,@AlmacenDestino,@Observaciones)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Considero que debería agregar try catch a su código y poner un punto de interrupción en el catch para ver el error, el que incluso podría estar en su conversión a entero de la cantidad,